# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 {n\choose k} = n(n+1)2^{n-2}$.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to figure out how to prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 {n\choose k} = n(n+1)2^{n-2}$$
I suspect that it has to do with using $$2^{n-2} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {n-2 \choose k-1}$$
But I'm really not sure. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You should maybe consider to search here on MSE *before* asking a question since your [last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2984542/show-that-sum-k-1n-kn-choose-k-n2n-1-for-all-n-in-z) - which is by the way quite similiar to this one - was a duplicate as well.

Comment: Are you aware about derivatives or you need to derive it without that?

Comment: Algebraic combinatorics is an entirely different topic.

Comment: Are you going to ask about $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^3\binom nk$$ tomorrow?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

We have that

$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n x^k\binom{n}{k}$$

then derive twice and set a convenient value for $x$.